# What should be validated first token or parameters?

Tags: rest, validation, bearer-token

Imagine I have 2 routes in my application:

- `POST /login -> {token: some_token}`
  route for authentication that returns token for accessing second function
- `POST /divide -> {result: x / y}`
  route for simulate function `divide(x: int, y: int)`, that protected by token bearer from first route. Also in this function I have some validators, i.e. `x` and `y` must be integers, `y` must be not equal 0 and it returns 400: BadRequest if one of those criteria is failed

So, my question is, if user didn't provide token bearer and parameters for route `/divide`, should I return 401 or 400?

There're two things that concerns me

- return 400: user can figure out my API structure by sending
  empty body and parse response, like send empty body and get {x: must be provided, y:
  must be provided}, then send x=abc,y=bca and get {x: must be integer,
  y: must be integer}, etc...
- return 401: user can DDoS my application by sending a lot of
  random tokens, so for each request application should check storage if token valid or not

What is the best practice in that case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without authorization you should in no way process any of the other content. Else, why have authentication/authorization at all? If you do process the content while the user is unauthorized you basically have a security breach. Obviously for the example function that does not seem like much of an issue, but that is the gist of it.

So you should return 401.

In case of the DDoS problem, that is not solved by processing in different order, you would still have to check all the tokens. And even if you did not someone could DDoS your service/API. There are other (API Management) solutions for that, like throttling, white-listing, rate-limiting etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like "opinion" question but i'll answer.
You need to return 401, becouse authorization is first thing you should do. Only if user can access resource, we can continue process.